# Dynamic Jsp pages - Taking too long

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a project which gives the user interface to create the Dynamic forms on the fly.
User can select different fields like `textbox`, `textarea`, date etc and create a model for the same.

Once the user chooses the component and creates a form, then we need to show that form at a specifies place. The form components are rendered through common jsp page which accepts pojo object and then distributes that object to our own custom created tags for input,checkbox,radio,date etc.

> Issue is it takes very 10-15 seconds to render the form.

Is there a way i can create templates or say html code of created forms and store them in DB and render through them. (Provided i am able to still bind data using Spring MVC, show `dropdown` values, selected or saved data in the fields.)

Comment: Can you provide a sample form that takes 10-15 seconds to render?

Comment: Actually speaking, this is not a static form instead a dynamic form. Meaning i have one common jsp page which renders different forms.
When i say i have a user interface from where one can design a form and create different components, so these components are stored in a DB in the form of entities, the while rendering these fields are loaded and converted to proper POJO, which is passed to that same common jsp to render.. Now from here it takes 1--15 seconds to process it internally.. and paint the whole form..

Comment: Yes, but we cannot advice you without determining why it takes that long.

Comment: Are you certain that the time isn't being taken up pulling the objects out of the database? For example if you're iterating over a query set which is lazily initialized, it may be doing a new SELECT for each entity.

Comment: It is redundant to say `jsp pages`. JSP stands for `JavaServer Pages` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org). It renders different forms inside a common JSP as you describe, and does not have the 10-15 second issue you are seeing.

Metawidget is Open Source, so you can examine how it works, or even use it 'as is' (it is designed to be embedded inside projects such as yours). There's a good example tutorial here: http://metawidget.org/doc/reference/en/html/ch01s03.html#section-introduction-part2-web

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to create you own custom tags and remove repeated code.
This will decrease the compilation time and further decreases the loading time of the page.